# Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer - Is There a Non-Recurring Version of This? (A Simple Delay)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, callback

`Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer` is a convenient method to repeatedly call some code in a certain interval. This is similar to JavaScript's `SetInverval()` method. JavaScript also has a method to set a single delay, called `SetTimeout()` - it delays a certain amount of time, then calls the callback code once. Is there a `SetTimeout` equivalent for Xamarin.Forms, where I simply want the code to be called in the background after a certain delay?

NOTE: I know I can `return false` to stop the recurrence, and that's easy enough. It just seems like if you're only intending to call the callback once, it's a little semantically misleading to use this recurring timer mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

[StartTimer](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer/p/System.TimeSpan/System.Func%7BSystem.Boolean%7D/#Remarks) will do this

> While the callback returns true, the timer will keep recurring.

Simply return `false` to stop the timer

Comment: Thanks - see my updated answer with the note at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could start a `Task` with delay:

```
async Task DoSomethingOnceWithDelay(TimeSpan delay)
{
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    await MyTask();
}
```

[Official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Delay_System_TimeSpan_).